# create a simple example of tasking error and storage error

Tags: ada

I need some simple Ada code for test my "system". In order to test it I need some example of code that raise a **storage error** and a **tasking error** (I know normally they are avoided but I need to simulate this problems). I know that seems a basic request but I am a little new on ada coding and I find a little difficult to solve these tasks. I have tried to search on the internet for a fitted solution but all are not usable for my needs(or too specific or wrong). What I am searching is to create an ***.adb*** with a function/procedure that raises these two errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you’ll be happy with different procedures for the two errors?

For `Storage_Error`,

```ada
procedure Storage is
   procedure Recursive is
   begin
      Recursive;
   end Recursive;
begin
   Recursive;
end Storage;
```

and for `Tasking_Error`,

```ada
procedure Tasking is
   task T is
      entry E;
   end T;
   task body T is
   begin
      null;
   end;
begin
   delay 0.01;
   T.E;
end Tasking;
```

This raises the exception because, when the main program calls `T.E`, there’s no task there at all. To explore this, replace the `null;` by e.g. `delay 5.0;` - the program waits 5 seconds before the exception terminates it.